# link_to using PUT method syntax to a different controller in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, link-to, put

I try to call an action of my Gallery controller from a Portfolio view. A Portfolio is made of many galleries.

I try this:

```
<%= link_to("Heart", gallery_path(gallery), :action => "like", :method => :put ,  :remote => true) %>

<%= link_to("Heart", :controller => :galleries, :action => "like", :method => :put ,  :remote => true) %>
```

And I obtain:

```
<a href="/galleries/3" action="like" data-method="put" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">Heart</a>
```

and

```
<a href="/galleries/1/like?method=put" data-remote="true">Heart</a>
```

I want to get but i m stuck...:

```
<a href="/galleries/3/like" data-method="put" data-remote="true">Heart</a>
```

Any RAILS God to help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're getting behaviour because you're trying to use the "path helper" and "params hash" styles in the same `link_to` (see [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) for more details).  I prefer the path helper style, so I'd write the link like this:

```
<%= link_to(
    'Heart',
    like_gallery_path(gallery),
    {:method => :put, :remote => true}
) %>
```

If you like the params hash style, you'd write:

```
<%= link_to(
    'Heart',
    {:controller => 'galleries', :action => 'like', :id => gallery.id},
    {:method => :put, :remote => true}
) %>
```

Note that the URL parameters (controller, action, etc.) are in a separate hash from the link parameters (method & remote).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
<%= link_to "Heart", gallery_path(gallery), :url => { :controller => "galleries", :action => "like"}, :method => :put, :remote => true)  %>
```